# error : uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, switch-statement

I'm learning ruby. I have three classes.Using switch case i'm trying call methods of other two classes in my first class.But getting an error uninitialized constant.

```
 class MainClass < Subtraction

 def operation(operate)
   case operate
     when Subtraction.new
     puts "abc"
   end
 end

 end
```

Comment: what error you recieve?

Comment: uninitialized constant error

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
def operation(operate)
   case operate
     when operate.class == Subtraction && operate.new_record?
     puts "abc"
   else
     puts "Something Else"
   end
end
```